# Casting an integer to Enum

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have Table like this

```
Id MagNo MagSeason MagYear
 1  1       0        2010
 2  2       1        2010
 3  3       2        2010
 4  4       3        2010
```

the **MagSeason** Field is an **Enum in MagazineDefault ViewModels** like this

```
public enum Season
{       
    Spring=0,        
    Summer=1,        
    Autumn=2,
    Winter=3
}
```

in List View of Magazine how can i have this

```
  No   Season      MagYear
  1    Spring       2010
  2    Summer       2010
  3    Autumn       2010
  4    Winter       2010
```

i cast like this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>(Cinema.ViewModel.Season) int.Parse(item.MagSeason))
```

but it gave the error

```
"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."
```

where have i made mistake?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your error, **DisplayFor** wants an expression that refers to a member of your model. The **parameter** to **DisplayFor** must be a property or field

You can simply do it like

```
 MyEnum myEnum = (MyEnum)myInt;
```

Additionaly, I would also check it is in range using [Enum.IsDefined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined.aspx):

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), myInt)) { 
   // it is defined
}
```

Comment: i have this ,(Cinema.ViewModel.Season) item.MagSeason , the Cinema.ViewModel.Season is the Enum, so why i get the error message?

Comment: @nnmmss, DisplayFor wants an expression that refers to a member of your model. Try `@Html.Display("something", (Cinema.ViewModel.Season) item.MagSeason)`

Comment: hwo should i do that? sorry i am compeletely new to the MVC

Comment: Thank you Satpal, but it shows nothing in Season , it is empty

Comment: I Added a property to model in partial class, and then cast to Enum as you said in there and my problem solved there. thank you. but still didn't understand why i couldn't see anything in Html.Display